# Maximum response PDU size of a remote system

Tags: networking, snmp, net-snmp, snmp4j

I am developing a SNMP poller which will poll around 40K devices every hour for CPU,Memory,Bandwidth and Connection Count related information. I am currently using snmp4j API. I am performing a snmpwalk separately for CPU, Memory, Bandwidth and Connection Count, but given the number of devices, this is taking huge amount of time. I am thinking of using SNMP getbulk request to get all the information at once, but this is restricted by the maximum response PDU packet size of the queried device. I wanted to know is there a way to know the maximum PDU response size of the remote system so that I can break up my request PDU accordingly. I have around 2500 OIDs to poll in one request. And also, I am not allowed to modify the response packet size of the remote system.

Answer (score 0):

This has been a problem for 30 years (SNMP is that old): part of device discovery is to determine max response size (in addition to response time, supported versions, etc) of each device.

It's basically a trade-off of discovery time vs. just assuming some minimal capabilities.